# Is it possible to modify the inner color of an svg image onclick

Tags: html, css, image, svg

I have an image of a star, the inner color obviously is transparent, I was wondering if I can onclick change the inner color like in a star rating for example.
Just using html CSS without any scripts.[blank star](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EyMa.png)

-tried the fill option but it only modifies the outer line of the star.
-tried using svg tags object tags but again doesn't fill the star.

I'm thinking my only option to have another image filled and interchange between them...

Comment: Can you please show us the code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Hey Aben! Did my answer solved your question? If it did: ¿can you mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can change the inner color of the star `onclick`, but you do need a small js to add a class to the object. If it was just a `rollover` you would be able to do it with just the CSS, adding a `:hover` state to the class definition of the element.

In order to achieve both, the SVG must be HTML-inlined, so it is part of the DOM.

Regarding your question:

> -tried the fill option but it only modifies the outer line of the star. -tried using svg tags object tags but again doesn't fill the star.

In order to change the fill color of an object, you have to change the attribute `fill`, like so:

```css
.star-holder{
width:6rem; 
height:6rem;
}

.star-holder img {
width: 100%
height:auto;
}

.star {
fill:#666
}

.star:hover {
fill:#f29111;
}
```

```html
<h3> Star rollover demo</h3>

<div class="star-holder">
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 viewBox="0 0 1278.000000 1280.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">

<g transform="translate(0.000000,1280.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
 stroke="none" class="star">
<path d="M6760 12443 c-137 -26 -302 -163 -453 -375 -207 -293 -384 -645 -802
-1598 -347 -790 -486 -1070 -667 -1337 -211 -311 -357 -373 -878 -374 -303 0
-573 22 -1315 106 -310 36 -666 73 -930 97 -191 17 -792 17 -905 0 -359 -56
-525 -174 -538 -382 -7 -128 43 -265 161 -442 197 -294 514 -612 1317 -1323
955 -845 1247 -1174 1290 -1452 37 -234 -95 -656 -453 -1458 -364 -816 -430
-963 -490 -1110 -252 -611 -352 -998 -318 -1236 31 -222 145 -333 357 -346
311 -21 768 169 1699 704 749 431 885 508 1051 596 451 240 718 338 924 341
121 1 161 -10 310 -84 265 -133 574 -380 1300 -1040 1006 -916 1405 -1206
1752 -1276 102 -21 173 -13 255 27 103 50 160 135 204 304 21 81 23 111 23
315 0 125 -5 267 -12 320 -51 379 -107 674 -253 1335 -229 1034 -279 1327
-279 1647 0 162 16 260 55 346 101 221 462 490 1275 952 661 375 831 473 1005
578 739 446 1065 761 1065 1027 0 155 -96 273 -306 378 -300 150 -748 236
-1764 342 -1052 108 -1334 148 -1637 225 -387 100 -514 201 -648 515 -117 276
-211 629 -391 1482 -135 644 -212 973 -289 1237 -115 398 -240 668 -380 824
-94 105 -221 156 -335 135z"/>
</g>
</svg>


</div>
```

A star rating system requires a script to save the state of the star when the user clicks on it, among other things. You may want to check this repo [that already has the star system working with SVG](https://nashio.github.io/star-rating-svg/demo/)

Answer (score 2):

You will need both filled and non-filled SVGs, and you can switch between the two on click.  For example, if you are using icon library such as font-awesome, you could switch between their star icons which come in flavors of 'regular' and 'solid'.

You could also manipulate the `fill` attribute of SVG, but it really depends on how the SVG is constructed, and what path elements are used in it and whether one can use fill with it or not.

```js
$('i').click((ev) => {
  $(ev.target).toggleClass('fa-star')
  $(ev.target).toggleClass('fa-star-o')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
```

Comment: Good demo, @wand-maker

Answer (score 0):

You can try to play with something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>

  <svg width="200" height="250" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

    <polygon points="50 160 55 180 70 180 60 190 65 205 50 195 35 205 40 190 30 180 45 180" stroke="green" fill="red" stroke-width="3"/>

  </svg>
```

Use 'stroke' for fill color and 'fill' for star silhouette.

And for the first part of the question. Changing css on click without js. 
https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/

Comment: I didn't know this one! great stuff!. I do like that the author specifies that it is a hack: 'Some of this stuff crosses the line of what you "should" do with CSS and introduces some questionable semantics. It's still very fun to play with and cool that it's possible, but in general, functional behavior should be controlled by JavaScript.'

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to modify the inner color of an svg image onclick?

Yes, there are many approaches to produce this result.

Here's one which uses SVG data URLs in CSS and Javascript.

**Working Example:**

```js
let stars = [...document.getElementsByClassName('star')];

const highlightStars = (event) => {

  let targetStar = event.target;
  let targetStarIndex = stars.indexOf(targetStar);
  targetStar.classList.toggle('highlighted');
  
  for (star of stars) {
    
    if (stars.indexOf(star) > (targetStarIndex - 1)) {
      star.classList.add('highlighted');
    }
      
    else {
      star.classList.remove('highlighted');
    }
  }
}

for (star of stars) {

  star.addEventListener('click', highlightStars, false);
}
```

```css
.ratings {
  float: left;
  width: 520px;
}

.star,
.ratings:hover .star {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
  height: 108px;
  background: rgb(191, 191, 191) url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 198 198"><polygon points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198" fill="rgb(255, 255, 255)"></polygon></svg>') no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ratings:hover .star:hover,
.star:hover ~ .star,
.star.highlighted {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255) url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 198 198"><polygon points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198" fill="rgb(255, 255, 0)"></polygon></svg>') no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="ratings">
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
  <div class="star"></div>
</div>
```

---

**N.B.** I know you wrote:

> Just using html CSS without any scripts

but it's always worth keeping in mind that:

- HTML describes structure
- CSS describes presentation
- Javascript describes behaviour

so if you want elements to present differently following a user's click-interaction, then javascript is absolutely the right tool to listen for clicks and update the CSS when it hears one.